# Is this rose seed going to germinate?

Tags: seeds, germination, perennials, roses

I am trying to germinate this rose seed, first I soaked this one seed into the egg incubator at 40 celsius lukewarm temperature water for nearly 1 week or less. Before when it was unsoaked I saw its seed coat is yellow, after soaking its seed coat turned half mixed yellowish with little reddish color, next when I put this seed into a terracotta pot and sprayed it, its coat turns fully reddish brown then its coat splits and inside theres a white thing from it but no signs of a stem coming out through it, does this mean its embryo is dead inside or still alive from the warm soaking that I just did? Is it still going to germinate if I wait longer? I think its white embryo inside is plumper now than last time when I tried to germinate it without soaking in the warm water then put into the soil and it looks skinny or flattish.
[image: THE ROSE SEED]

Comment: How old was the rosehip you collected and carried out this procedure with - from last year or  only in the last few weeks?

Comment: I bought this renee's garden miniature rose angel wing seed packet from the gardenworks store, it doesn't say anything about stratification

Comment: I don't know how old this rose seed is, I just bought it few months ago, this procedure was carried out few weeks ago

Comment: Is this what you mean, and did you follow these instructions https://www.reneesgarden.com/products/rose-miniature-angel-wings